# С++ Передать массив в функцию и не потерять автозаполнение

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Питаюсь передать массив в метод класса, но для этого нужно переделать массив в указатель, но когда массив стает указателем то я не могу ему присвоить сразу все нужные элементы.

Вот пример
Класс

```
class MeshT
{
public: 
    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;  //створитиизмінні для буферів
    MeshT(GLfloat* vertices,int vs,GLint* indices,int is)
    {

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); //Згенерувати буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); //зв'язую наш буфер з Open GL
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vs, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //Передати дані на відеокарту

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, is, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,6 * sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)( sizeof(GLfloat)*3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);



    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO


    }

    void draw()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    ~MeshT()
    {
        // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    }
};
```

Строки из main Пока что vertices и indices не указатели потому что иначе я не могу присвоить им данные в формате = {1,2,3,4,5,*}

```
  GLfloat vertices[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1,0,0,  // Top Right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0,1,1, // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1,1,0, // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f ,1,0,1 // Top Left 
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // First Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // Second Triangle
    };

    MeshT CVDRAT(vertices,sizeof(vertices),indices ,sizeof(indices));
```

Comment: В С++, вроде бы как, нельзя присваивать массивам все (или частично) элементы за один раз. Совсем нельзя. Разве только через memset()/memcopy() - но это уже другая история. То что Вы делаете - называется "инициализация", и этим занимается компилятор на стадии компиляции. Если Вы хотите потом присваивать массивы целиком, то возможно, Вам помогут вектора или массивы из STL (Вы же на С++ пишете?).

Comment: #include<vector>

Comment: А как вектору присвоить сразу несколько элементов ?

Comment: Через перегруженный оператор присваивания: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/   или метод assign(): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/ . Но они могут и не справиться с тем, что Вам надо (я же не знаю, что именно требуется).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из ситуации переместив всё в файлы

```
class MeshT
{
public: 
    std::vector<int>vec1;


    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;  //створитиизмінні для буферів
    MeshT(std::string urlV,std::string urlI)
    {


    //===========================================================
    GLfloat* a;
    int av;
    {
        std::vector<float>t;
        ifstream f(urlV.c_str());
        if(!f) return;
        while (!f.eof()) {
          float n;
          f >> n;
          t.push_back(n);
        }
        f.close();
        a = new GLfloat[t.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<t.size()) {a[i] = t[i]; i++;}
        av = t.size();
    }

    //===========================================================
    GLint* in;
    int inv;
    {
        std::vector<GLint>t;
        ifstream f(urlI.c_str());
        if(!f) return;
        while (!f.eof()) {
          GLint n;
          f >> n;
          t.push_back(n);
        }
        f.close();
        in = new GLint[t.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<t.size()) {in[i] = t[i]; i++;}
        inv = t.size();
    }










         //GLfloat* vertices,int vs,GLint* indices,int is   
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); //Згенерувати буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); //зв'язую наш буфер з Open GL
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat) * av, a, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //Передати дані на відеокарту

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint)*inv, in, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,6 * sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)( sizeof(GLfloat)*3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);



    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO


    }

    void draw()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    ~MeshT()
    {
        // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    }
};
```

Вызов даже лучше вышло

```
MeshT CVDRAT("Cube.vertex","Cube.index");
```